# Get indexes for intersection

Tags: c#, linq, intersection, set-intersection

I have a problem. I'm finding an intersection using the code below:

```
Envelope[][] extents = new Envelope[tilesCountX][tilesCountY];

// some code here to set "extents" values

var intersectedTiles =
    extents
    .SelectMany(es => es)
    .Where(e => EnvIntersects(e, bounds))
    .ToList();

private static bool EnvIntersects(Envelope e1, Envelope e2)
{
    return e1.MinX >= e2.MinX && e1.MaxX <= e2.MaxX && e1.MinY >= e2.MinY && e1.MaxY <= e2.MaxY;
}
```

It works but I want to get the indexes of intersected extents.

**e.g.**
If `extents[2][7]` is an intersected element, I want to get `2` and `7`.

Is it possible by modifying my code?

**[edit]**

`bounds` is an `Envelope` that has `MinX`, `MinY`, `MaxX` and `MaxY` properties inside.

```
Envelope bounds = new Envelope();
bounds.MinX = some_value_1;
bounds.MaxX = some_value_2;
bounds.MinY = some_value_3;
bounds.MaxY = some_value_4;
```

Comment: Where does 'bounds' come from?  And the SelectMany seems out of place.

Comment: what version of C# are you using? `Envelope[][] extents = new Envelope[tilesCountX][tilesCountY];` does not compile for me in .NET 4.0

Comment: Your `EnvIntersects` requires a much stricter condition than what I would call 'intersection', btw.

Comment: @w0lf I know, but I wrote `tilesCountY` in order to tell u about `Y-size` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this could also give you what you want:

```csharp
var intersectedIndices =
    from x in Enumerable.Range(0, tilesCountX)
    from y in Enumerable.Range(0, tilesCountY)
    where EnvIntersects(extents[x, y], bounds)
    select new { x, y };
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var intersectedTiles =
extents
.SelectMany((es,i) => es.Select((x,j)=>new{I=i,J=j,Element = x}))
.Where(e => EnvIntersects(e.Element, bounds))
.ToList();
```

where for all elements in intersectedTiles this is true:

```
intersectedTiles[x].Element == extents[intersectedTiles[x].I][intersectedTiles[x].J]
```